# How do I make the cover photo appear on iPhone Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, background-image, mobile-safari

The website where the cover photo won't appear is [here](http://www.alltheoptions.co.uk).

This error is persistent for Safari on any iOS device but works for Safari on Mac.

This is the CSS:

```
.bg-img {
    /* The image used */
    background: url("../images/background.jpeg") 0 0;
    background-size: auto;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    background-color: rgba(41, 39, 34, 0.50);
    max-width: 100%;    
}
```

And the HTML is just one section that references the CSS as such:

```
<section id="home" class="home bg-img parralax fix">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this was the `parralax` in the HTML below.

```
<section id="home" class="home bg-img parralax fix">
```

This was interfering with `bg-img` hence why it wouldn't display the image.